# How to select a random record for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table like

```
 |    A   | B | C | D |
 |--------|---|---|---|
 | Value1 | x | x | x |
 | Value1 | y | x | y |
 | Value1 | x | x | x |
 |        ....        |
 | Value2 | x | x | x |
 | Value2 | x | x | x |
 | Value2 | x | x | x |
 |        ....        |
 | Value3 | x | x | x |
 | Value3 | x | x | x |
 | Value3 | x | x | x |
```

where `A` column can have one value from a set. I want to get a random record for each unique value in `A` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a) a, b, c, d
from test t;
```

[Here is a Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9eed33cc532dc8ce20347c0e892bdaba)

> With DISTINCT ON, You tell PostgreSQL to return a single row for each
> distinct group defined by the ON clause.

More about that subject here: https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/

Comment: Please note that `distinct on` without `order by` is not random: it is *undefined*, which is a different thing. Random is, on the other hand, a well-defined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by a order by random()) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

`row_number()` assigns a random rank to each record within groups having the same `a`; then, the outer query filters one record per group.

Actually, since you are running Postgres, you could as well use `distinct on`, which could give better performance (and a shorter syntax):

```
select distinct on (a) t.*
from mytable t
order by a, random();
```